# Inserting QRCode to Database

Tags: excel, vba, qr-code

[image]I have some code that inserts a qrcode based on a userform that is filled out. The qrcode inserts properly, however, I cannot get the qrcode to insert into the last cell in column G. The information entered in the userform is entered in a database so I was thinking and finding the last entry and using .offset, But I could not get it to work. This is the code I have:

```
    Sub GenerateSingleQRCode()
    Dim QRPic As String, QRURL As String, QRData As String, ForeCol As String, BackCol As String
    Dim QRSize As Long, LastRow As Long, ItemRow As Long
    Dim targetRow As Integer
    Dim rngAnchor As Range
    Dim Sh As Shape
    
    With Worksheets("Database")
            
            
            On Error Resume Next
            .Shapes("QRItemPic").Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
            QRData = vbNewLine & "Part Number: " & txtPartNumber & vbNewLine & "Description: " & txtDescription & vbNewLine & "Supplier: " & txtSupplier & vbNewLine & "Product Line: " & partInfoProductLine  'Item Name (QR Data)
            QRSize = Worksheets("Setup").Range("C5").Value 'Large QR Size
            ForeCol = Right("00000" & Hex(Worksheets("Setup").Range("C4").Value), 6)
            ForeCol = Right(ForeCol, 2) & Mid(ForeCol, 3, 2) & Left(ForeCol, 2)
            BackCol = Right("00000" & Hex(Worksheets("Setup").Range("C3").Value), 6)
            BackCol = Right(BackCol, 2) & Mid(BackCol, 3, 2) & Left(BackCol, 2)
            QRURL = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=" & QRData & "&size=" & QRSize & "x" & QRSize & _
            "&charset-source=UTF-8&charset-target-=UTF-8ecc=L&color=" & ForeCol & "&bgcolor=" & BackCol & _
            "&margin=0&qzone=1&format=png"
            With Worksheets("Database").Pictures.Insert(QRURL)
                
                
            End With
            End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, you're using a webpage to generate the QR code? Last time I had a need I wrote a custom plugin in C# using [ZXing](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net). Looks like you can just download an [addin](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104051163)

Comment: This looks like Excel. It should be noted that Excel is not a database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA Excel Adding pictures to a worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797500/vba-excel-adding-pictures-to-a-worksheet)

Comment: No, When I said "Database" I meant an excel table. It is inserting the QRcode correctly. I just need the qrcode to be inserted in the last row in Column G.

Comment: Well, image objects don't necessarily exist inside rows or columns. They are objects that float above the sheet. You can align them to cells. So your question is how to move a picture object to a cell location? Because that's a [question that has been asked and answered too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399514/how-to-move-image-in-excel-using-vba)

Comment: I figured that. That is why I thought their would be an easy solution. The userform enters information at the bottom of the table in A through F. Is there not a way to reference the last value in Column F and offset over 1 to column G and insert?

Comment: Added a picture to explain what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the next way:

Replace this part of your code:

```
        With Worksheets("Database").Pictures.Insert(QRURL)
                
                
        End With
```

with this one:

```
            Set wsDB = Worksheets("Database")
            Set rng = wsDB.Range("G" & wsDB.Range("F" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row)
            With .Pictures.Insert(QRURL)
                .top = rng.top + (rng.height - .height) / 2
                .left = rng.left + (rng.width - .width) / 2
            End With
```

This modification will place the QR code in the last cell of G:G, **but based on the last value in column F:F**. I mean, the QR code will be placed in the cell near the last value in F:F... Centered on the cell from G:G column.

Comment: It it possible to get it Inside the cell? I am new to VBA, but I am not really sure why it is possible with a picture but not with this qrcode?

Comment: Isn,t it positioned on top left cell side? I mean, its top left corner..

Comment: It is not possible to be "inside" the cell. Only text can be inside the cell. Even when you have a picture that covers the cell completely and resizes with the cell, the cell underneath still has editable text inside it. The picture is a floating OLE object that is "above" the spreadsheet in the Z direction.

Comment: @inmoint Do you mean to be centered on the cell? Is the cell in discussion always wide/high enough to accept it in its (pseudo) interior? If yes, I can adapt the code. It should be simple arithmetic, related to code picture and cell size. Adapted the code to center the QR picture on the cell. Was this what you wonted?

Comment: @inmoint Didn't you find some time to test the requested solution? If tested, didn't it do what you wont?